# 'import' is not a valid type keyword in variable declaration

Tags: pine-script

Im new to pine script
I tried to write a pine script in tradingview editor but im getting an error which I dont understand why.
Error:
Line 6: 'import' is not a valid type keyword in variable declaration

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
    // © technicalCloud9c0c4
    
    //@version=4
    // Import specific functions from the ta library
    import TradingView/ta/4
    study('WTWS & C [xxx]', shorttitle='WTWS+C CB', overlay=true)
```

To import library I need to use "import"

I need to to use //@version=4 dont want to change //@version=5

How to solve this error?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. `import` is not a valid keyword in `v4` so you **MUST** update your code to `v5`.

Try using the auto converter tool. It does a pretty good job.

Or copy the functions you need from that library and convert them to `v4`.